# How to perform code signing by retrieving azure key vault certificate?

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, x509certificate, azure-keyvault

I am trying to retrieve the Azure key vault certificate with PowerShell to perform code signing.

````
$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName kv -Name CodeSigning -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($pfxSecret)
$x509Cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$x509Cert.Import($secretByte, $null, [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)

Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Users\Desktop\*.dll $pfxFileByte -TimestampServer http://timestamp.digicert.com
```.
````

Is there any other way to retrieve the Azure keyvault certificate and perform code signing?

Comment: The error message is telling you that it's expecting a cert object rather than the raw bytes. Skip the `$pfxFileBytes = ...` step and try passing the `$x509Cert` object to the command instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot convert 'System.Byte[]' to the type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2' required by parameter 'Certificate'. Specified method is not supported.
```

is telling you that the argument bound to the `-Certificate` parameter is of type `[byte[]]` - meaning it's a byte array - and that PowerShell's parameter binder cannot convert it to an object of type `[509Certificate2]`.

`$pfxFileBytes` is the only argument for which you haven't explicitly specified a parameter name, so it's safe to assume that argument is the problematic one.

Since you already have the certificate in the required format, stored in `$x509Cert`, pass that instead:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Users\Desktop\*.dll -Certificate $x509Cert -TimestampServer http://timestamp.digicert.com
```

Comment: @praharshinis You're most welcome. Consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark icon outlined on the left

Comment: How to sign CAT file based on an INF file ?